# Empty output file when trying to write a struct in

Tags: c, file, structure

I have a project of a phone book, I have a function to read the structure from a file, put it into an array of structure.  So to make sure that it reads correctly I print it into an output file but the result of the output file,

```
  0    (null) 6553280
```

I have a CSV file with the data  like

```
Ahmed,Mohamed,26 Elhoreya Street,15,Alexandria,4876321,ahmed@gmail.com
Sarah,Zaki,7 Smouha,36,Alexandria,3974542,sarah@hotmail.com
```

> The output is null, it doesn't (read/write) correctly, while using the debugger it shows that it's reading.  Why?

```
int i;
int counter;

struct pb //main struct
{
    char Firstname[25];
    char Lastname[25];
    char street[20];
    int street_no ;
    char city[15];
    int number;
    char email[50];
};
struct pb k[1000];

void read_str(struct queue *queue)
{
    {
        counter = 0 ;
        FILE *read ;
        char filename[40];

        printf("Enter file name \n");
        scanf("%s",&filename);
        read=fopen(filename,"r");

        if (read == NULL)
            printf("Error");
        else
            while(!feof(read))
            {
                struct pb *n= malloc(sizeof(struct pb));
                fscanf(read,"%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%d,%[^,],%d,%s\n",
                    k[counter].Firstname, k[counter].Lastname,
                    k[counter].street, &k[counter].street_no, 
                    k[counter].city, &k[counter].number, k[counter].email );
                counter++;
            }
        fclose(read);
    }
}

int main()
{
    read_str(&k);
    FILE *read ;

    read=fopen("out.txt","w");
    fprintf(read,"%s %s %s %d %s %d %s ",
        k[counter].Firstname, k[counter].Lastname, 
        k[counter].street, k[counter].street_no, k[counter].city,  
        k[counter].number, k[counter].email );

    fclose(read);

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Wait, i don't see any question marks ... What is the question?

Comment: sorry, i edited defining the problem

Comment: `void read_str(struct queue *queue)` What is struct queue? you declared an array of struct pb

Comment: @Bob__ The call to `read_str` is the first line of `main()`

Comment: @Barmar: You are right, still the type mismatch remain

Comment: That's probably just a copying error.

Comment: @Barmar could i declare something ? .. the function asks for the txt file , so it's the start of the code in {main} , if there is any problem then it's not a copying one , what do i miss ?

Comment: @KhaledMohamedKhaled See smlq's answer, it explains what you did wrong. You're printing an uninitialized element of the `k` array.

Comment: `while (!feof(read))` -- See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: What didn't you understand about the warnings your compiler is giving you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can at least at a first glance see that the value of the `counter` during `fprintf` in `main` function is one past the end of your valid structure array (because of `counter++` after the `fscanf`), which means it is undefined.

Moreover, I think you want to run a loop to `fprintf` all the records (`struct`s). But you didn't.

Your orderings of `fscanf` and `fprintf` format specifiers are inconsistent.

It is clear that your code is doing nothing useful in the `main` function.

**Update**

Minimally corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int counter;

struct pb //main struct
{
    char Firstname[25];
    char Lastname[25];
    char street[20];
    int street_no ;
    char city[15];
    int number;
    char email[50];
};
struct pb k[1000];

void read_str()
{
    FILE *fin;
    char filename[40];
    counter = 0 ;
    printf("Enter file name \n");
    scanf("%s",filename);
    if((fin=fopen(filename,"r"))!=NULL)
    {
        while(!feof(fin))
        {
            fscanf(fin,"%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%d,%[^,],%d,%s\n",k[counter].Firstname, k[counter].Lastname, k[counter].street, &k[counter].street_no, k[counter].city, &k[counter].number, k[counter].email);
            ++counter;
        }
        fclose(fin);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    FILE *fout;
    read_str();
    if((fout=fopen("out.txt","w"))!=NULL)
    {
        for(i=0; i<counter; ++i)
        {
            fprintf(fout,"%s %s %d %s %s %s %d\n",
                    k[i].Firstname, k[i].Lastname, k[i].street_no,
                    k[i].street,k[i].city,k[i].email,k[i].number );
        }
        fclose(fout);
    }
    return 0 ;
}
```

N.B. There are still many caveats in this code.

Comment: okay, I got the counter issue but i'm not sure about the right solution,shall i enter it inside the function

Comment: What are the numbers 15 and 36? Your ordering of `fscanf` format specifier is inconsistent.

Comment: @smlq edited , but still have the [counter] issue ,what is its boundary condition for while loop ?

Comment: @smlq it worked well, if((fout=fopen("out.txt","w"))!=NULL) why you chose this condition ?

also please be noticed that i'm a still learning so i'd be grateful if you have time to tell me the major caveats you see 

thanks in advance & for the help

Comment: @Bob__: I understand that it can be improved. I only corrected his issue of getting the correct output. In fact, as you are saying about the global `counter` variable, the same is true for the `k` array.

Comment: @smlq: of course. It would be better to create a struct holding the array and its size... and so on.

Comment: @KhaledMohamedKhaled: That is because if it fails to open the file, `fopen` will return `NULL` in which case you ignore processing the file (here `writing to it`). Obviously, you can add `else printf("Error: could not open output file out.txt for writing.\n")` just before `return 0 ;` to display an warning message.

Comment: That it is. You would then require `malloc`, `realloc` and `free` functions to dynamically adjust the number of records (*i.e.* length of the `struct` array).

Comment: @Bob__ why it's better to make a new struct holding the array ?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to not writing beyond the end of your array-of-structs when reading your data, there are several additional areas where you may want to revise the approach you have taken with your code.

First, unless there is a compelling reason to declare your data structure as a global variable, you should limit its scope to `main()` and pass the array-of-structs as a parameter to any functions that need access to the data. In addition, when dealing with constants in your program (e.g. max phonebook entries `1000`), it is good practice to either define a constant (`#define MAXE 1000`) or preferably use an `enum` to define the constant, e.g.:

```
enum { MAXE = 1000 };
```

(An anonymous `enum` is fine.)

You can also simplify your life by creating a `typedef` to your struct as well which will make passing the array-of-structs as a parameter easier. For instance you can declare a `typedef` to your struct (either named or anonymous) as follows:

```
typedef struct {
    char Firstname[25];
    char Lastname[25];
    char street[20];
    int street_no ;
    char city[15];
    int number;
    char email[50];
} pb;
```

This will allow a simple declaration in `main()`, e.g.:

```
    pb k[MAXE] = {{{0},{0},{0},0,{0},0,{0}}};
```

While not required, it is also good practice to initialize all variables, (including your array-of-structs), when they are declared.

While in this instance, there is little difference between reading the data file with `fscanf` or using a *line-oriented* input function, you will generally find reading a line at a time with `fgets` or `getline` and then parsing the line into components with `sscanf` or simple pointers will provide a more flexible and robust input routine. Regardless whether you read with `fscanf` or read with `fgets` and parse with `sscanf` *always* check the returns of `fscanf` or `sscanf` to validate the number of successful conversions.

The benefit of using *line-oriented* input functions to read each line of text from your input file is it will eliminate the rigidity of the `fscanf` *format-string* from the actual read of the file and allow you to handle separating the values after the line has been successfully read into a buffer. An example of using `fgets` in your case could be:

```
/* read addresses from input file up to a maximum of MAXE
 * addresses. updates 'idx' pointer to hold the number of 
 * addreses read from file and returns number read
 */
size_t read_str (pb (*k)[], size_t *idx, FILE *fp)
{
    char tmp[MAXL] = {0};
    while (*idx < MAXE && fgets (tmp, MAXL, fp)) {
        // printf ("read[%zu]\n", *idx);
        if (sscanf (tmp, " %24[^,],%24[^,],%19[^,],%d,%14[^,],%d,%49[^\n]",
            (*k)[*idx].Firstname, (*k)[*idx].Lastname,
            (*k)[*idx].street, &(*k)[*idx].street_no, 
            (*k)[*idx].city, &(*k)[*idx].number, (*k)[*idx].email) != 7) {
            fprintf (stderr, "read_str() error: parse of line[%zu] failed.\n",
                     *idx);
            break;
        }
        (*idx)++;
    }

    return *idx;
}
```

**note** also the return of the number of address entries read allowing you to gauge *success/failure* of the function as well as providing you with the number of entries read. The number of entries read (`idx`) is also passed as a pointer to the function making the number of entries available in the calling function (`main()` here) regardless of whether the return is assigned.

Beyond those initial issues, you will want to validate each action you take that has consequence for the continued operation of your code. (e.g. all file opens, reads, writes, etc...) Putting those pieces together and adding basic validation, and using line oriented input, another approach to your task could look like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* constants for max input line and max entries */
enum { MAXL = 256, MAXE = 1000 };

typedef struct {
    char Firstname[25];
    char Lastname[25];
    char street[20];
    int street_no ;
    char city[15];
    int number;
    char email[50];
} pb;

size_t read_str (pb (*k)[], size_t *idx, FILE *fp);
void print_str_fmt (pb *k, size_t idx);
int print_str (pb *k, size_t idx, FILE *fp);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 3) { /* validate input/output filenames given as arguments */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input, usage: %s infile outfile\n",
                argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    pb k[MAXE] = {{{0},{0},{0},0,{0},0,{0}}}; /* initialize variables */
    size_t index = 0;
    FILE *ifp, *ofp;

    if (!(ifp = fopen (argv[1], "r"))) { /* validate input file open  */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    if (!(ofp = fopen (argv[2], "w"))) { /* validate output file open */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'\n", argv[2]);
        return 1;
    }

    if (!read_str (&k, &index, ifp)) { /* validate entries read */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: read_str - no addresses read\n");
        return 1;
    }
    fclose (ifp);   /* close input file  */

    printf ("The addresses are:\n\n");
    print_str_fmt (k, index);

    if (print_str (k, index, ofp)) {  /* validate entries written */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: print_str - no addresses read\n");
        return 1;
    }
    fclose (ofp);   /* close output file */

    return 0;
}

/* read addresses from input file up to a maximum of MAXE
 * addresses. updates 'idx' pointer to hold the number of 
 * addreses read from file and returns number read
 */
size_t read_str (pb (*k)[], size_t *idx, FILE *fp)
{
    char tmp[MAXL] = {0};
    while (*idx < MAXE && fgets (tmp, MAXL, fp)) {
        // printf ("read[%zu]\n", *idx);
        if (sscanf (tmp, " %24[^,],%24[^,],%19[^,],%d,%14[^,],%d,%49[^\n]",
            (*k)[*idx].Firstname, (*k)[*idx].Lastname,
            (*k)[*idx].street, &(*k)[*idx].street_no, 
            (*k)[*idx].city, &(*k)[*idx].number, (*k)[*idx].email) != 7) {
            fprintf (stderr, "read_str() error: parse of line[%zu] failed.\n",
                     *idx);
            break;
        }
        (*idx)++;
    }

    return *idx;
}

/* formatted print of addressbook to stdout */
void print_str_fmt (pb *k, size_t idx)
{
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++)
        printf (" %s %s\n %s No. %d\n %s, %d\n %s\n\n", 
                k[i].Firstname, k[i].Lastname, k[i].street, k[i].street_no,
                k[i].city, k[i].number, k[i].email);
}

int print_str (pb *k, size_t idx, FILE *fp)
{
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++)
        if (fprintf (fp, "%s,%s,%s,%d,%s,%d,%s\n", 
                    k[i].Firstname, k[i].Lastname, k[i].street, k[i].street_no,
                    k[i].city, k[i].number, k[i].email) < 0)
            return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

**Compile**

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -O3 -o bin/readstructsscanf readstructsscanf.c
```

**Test Input**

```
$ cat ../dat/phonebook.txt
Ahmed,Mohamed,26 Elhoreya Street,15,Alexandria,4876321,ahmed@gmail.com
Sarah,Zaki,7 Smouha,36,Alexandria,3974542,sarah@hotmail.com
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/readstructsscanf ../dat/phonebook.txt foo.txt
The addresses are:

 Ahmed, Mohamed
 26 Elhoreya Street No. 15
 Alexandria, 4876321
 ahmed@gmail.com

 Sarah, Zaki
 7 Smouha No. 36
 Alexandria, 3974542
 sarah@hotmail.com
```

**Confirm Output File**

```
$ diff ../dat/phonebook.txt foo.txt
$
```

As with all problems in C, there are usually many ways to approach a correct solution. Hopefully this will give you a few additional ideas on how to make your code more flexible and robust.

Comment: I really didn't get the { gcc -Wall -Wextra -O3 -o bin/readstructsscanf readstructsscanf.c }

i even couldn't try the code !

Comment: If you are not using Linux/gcc, then that compile string *does not* apply. Compile as you normally would on whatever OS you are using. However, you should *always* use the `-Wall` and `-Wextra` compile options to enable compiler warnings, and the `-O3` is simply optimization level `3`. Try compiling the code again with whatever compiler you are using.